# How to generate images with location on map offline?

Tags: python

I have a pair of coordinates (lat, long).
I need to generate an image of displaying these coordinates on the map.
And then generate such images with other coordinates in the future without the Internet.

Please tell me whether there are solutions that allow you to display coordinates offline?

Upd: is there any opportunity to download maps offline , eg: gps tracker maps or something like that?

thank you

Comment: your question is not composed well. what platform would you want to use for the map display

Comment: @NightKing , it doesn't matter to me which one to use

Comment: Do you need the entire world, or just a small bit? Do you need world-on-a-postcard maps or maps where every paving stone is visible? Is your platform a mobile phone, or a huge data center in a bomb-proof bunker with no connection to the outside?

Comment: @k2a i think some maps can be downloaded offline. check google-maps or mapbox

Comment: @TurePålsson ,i need a map of the whole world, preferably a scale of 1:1000000. 
The platform will be a computer with no connection to the outside

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible while offline.  To generate an image of the coordinate location you would most likely be using

```
os.system("open \"\" https://www.google.nl/maps/place/" + location)
```

and then generating a image of the location that is popped up.  This is impossible to do while offline, I am very sorry.

Comment: @Novy arcgis is literally short for arcgis online are there any offline capabilities for arcgis

Comment: @k2a to use an offline map you would have to download the whole map which would take up so much storage, using this offline just isn't possible I don't think.  However their might be a way to download part of a map but I have not looked into that yet, I will @ you when I learn more

Comment: Oh my bad. I was reading this [article](https://doc.arcgis.com/fr/arcgis-online/manage-data/take-maps-offline.htm) in their site I thought it was worth taking a look @SeaverOlson

Comment: @Novy I just saw that and I agree with you normally that would work, but for this request the user wants the full world downloaded with a 1:1M standard scaling

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad to give a good answer. However:

There are several companies, such as TeleAtlas and NavTeq, that sell map data. I have no idea what buying the world from them at 1:1M resolution would cost, but I'd guess several thousand USD.

You could download data, or pre-rendered rasters, from [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com). However, they don't have quite the resolution required for good 1:1M maps.

You could download data from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org). The data is free (as in beer, and as in speech), but using it is a major undertaking.

There are companies that offer pre-rendered maps in various formats from OpenStreetMap data. [OpenMapTiles](https://openmaptiles.org) is the one I happen to have at the top of my head, but here are others.